# Python concatenate 2D array to new list if condition is met

Tags: python, append, concatenation

Let's say I have an array:

```
print(arr1.shape)
(188621, 10)
```

And in the nth column (let's say 4 for this example), I want to check when a value is above a threshold, t. I want to create a new list (of x instances) of the entire row of arr1 when the ith iteration of the 4th column is above threshold t. In other words, it is extracting the ith row from arr1 when the condition in the 4th column is met. So far I have:

arr2 = []

```
for i in range(0,len(arr1)):
   if arr1[i,4] > t:
      arr2.append(arr1[i,:])
```

I have also tried something along the lines of:

```
for i in range(0,len(arr1)):
   if arr1[i,4] > t:
      if len(arr2) == 0:
         arr2 = arr1[i,:]
      else:
         arr2 = np.concatenate((arr2,arr1[i,:]))
```

However, both instances seem to be growing in 1D terms of x*10 instead of a 2D list of (x, 10) when the conditions are met. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it wasn't that difficult.

arr2 = arr1[np.logical_not(arr1[:,4] < t)]